# Gradle Copy task: Ant to gradle migration

Tags: gradle, ant, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-eclipse

I am new to gradle and migrating ant build.xml script to gradle. Usually copy tasks are fairly simple and straight forward but i came across this little complex copy task (might be simple as well) which has verbose enabled and fileset. Can I know how to convert this ant code to gradle task ?

```
<copy todir="client" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="${build.classes}">
        <include name="com/corp/domain/**" />                   
      </fileset>
   </copy>
```

Gradle task i tried to write so far is

```
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
  from 'dist'
  include "com/corp/domain/**"
  into 'client'
}
```

I need to know how fileset and verbose can come into picture to make it perfect migrated task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Gradle task is already doing almost everything right. A [`<fileset>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) in Ant is a group of files. Using `dir=`, you can start in one directory and include or exclude a subset of all files in this directory. This behaviour is already implemented by the Gradle [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) task, because it implements the [`CopySpec`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html) interface. So, for only one Ant `<fileset>` you can use the `Copy` task and its methods, like you did in your example:

```
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
    from 'path/to/dir'
    include 'com/corp/domain/**'
    into 'client'
}
```

If you need to use multiple `<fileset>` elements, you can add a child `CopySpec` for each of them, e.g. by using the `from` method followed by a closure. The configurations in this closure will only apply to the files from this directory, just like configuring a single `<fileset>`:

```
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
    from('dir1') {
        include 'foo/bar'
    }
    from('dir2') {
        exclude 'bar/foo'
    }
    into 'dir3'
}
```

`${build.classes}` refers to an Ant property. Since Gradle is based on Groovy, you could define your property in various places and ways (e.g. [extra properties](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html)), but please mind that `build` is the name of a task, which is present in nearly all Gradle build scripts, so using `build.classes` directly would propably look for the property in the scope of the `build` task:

```
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
    // if you defined the property before
    from my.build.classes
    include 'com/corp/domain/**'
    into 'client'
}
```

The `verbose` attribute only defines whether all file copy operations should be logged on the console. Gradle does not support file logging via a simple option, so we need to implement it on our own. Luckily, Gradle provides the `eachFile` method. We can pass a closure, which is called for each copied file and carries a [`FileCopyDetails`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCopyDetails.html) object. I do not know how Ant logs the copied files, but one way could be the following:

```
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
    // ...
    eachFile { details ->
        println "Copying $details.sourcePath to $details.path ..."
    }
}
```

Comment: The best answer about Gradle I have seen so far, because it explains a lot about the Gradle details.

Answer (score -1):

@ronypatil, the following code could be a good reference for you to solve the problem:

```
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
    FileTree tree = fileTree("dist")
    tree.include "com/corp/domain/**"

    File toPath = file("client")

    tree.each { File file ->
        from file
        into toPath
        println "copy $file into $toPath"
    }
}
```